# Nvidia Quadro FX 570 + ATI Radeon B276 for 3+ Monitors?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a Dell T3400 Work computer that currently has 2 monitors hooked up through a Quadro FX 570, the Quadro only supports 2.
I need to add a 3rd monitor,
I am running windows 7 32-bit.
Could I add an ATI Radeon B276 to attach an additional monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just make sure that you have a sufficiently strong PSU and cables to connect it and that you did not already put other cards in your PCI-e slots.

According to [this](http://resources.avid.com/SupportFiles/attach/Dell%20T3400%20slot%20Guide%20Rev%20C.pdf) you should have two x16 and one x8 slots.  If nothing else is in them you could even use up to three graphics cards.

Comment: Thanks! I shall comment back when I get everything up and running.